# Profiling Gradle Projects

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, editor

How can I profile Gradle projects in Netbeans? I've looked in a few places, but they turned up dead ends. The profile button is also disabled in the Netbeans editor when using a Gradle project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start your application and use profiler's ability to attach to running JVM - `Profiler | Attach Profiler` in main menu.

In the past it was necessary to add some flags to your application to load special hooks used by profiler but it seems that this is no longer needed according to pages like http://wiki.netbeans.org/DynamicAttachDemo

Answer (score -1):

There is another, tool-agnostic way of profiling Gradle projects with [gradle-profiler](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-profiler)
. It's a standalone CLI tool that runs your build with a given parameters (tasks, clean-ups, warm-ups, different Gradle versions — all configurable) and generates perfomance reports.

Comment: this answer seems to address profiling of the gradle build itself, not the issue that the "profiler" option is disabled in netbeans when using gradle projects like asked in the Q. The Q is about profiling the running application.